# UITapGestureRecognizer not working on UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to a UILabel that will animate down from the status bar if the user has a new announcement. I want the user to be able to click the label and goto the announcement directly. The UITapGetureRecognizer isn't working. Here is what I am doing:

```
+(void)animateDown:(NSString *)title view:(UIViewController *)view color:(UIColor *)color time:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    view = view.navigationController.visibleViewController;
    if (currentlyDisplayed == NO) {
        if (color == nil) color = customGreen;
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,-40, 320, 40)];
        label.text = title;
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiTC-Medium" size:18];
        label.backgroundColor = color;//customBlue;//[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0993145 green:0.0957361 blue:0.562879 alpha:.8f];
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
        [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [label setMinimumFontSize:12];
        [label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [label sizeToFit];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        if ([color isEqual:customBlue]) {
            UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap:)];
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
            label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [label addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        }
        [view.view addSubview:label];
        [view.view bringSubviewToFront:label];
        currentlyDisplayed = YES;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.5f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            CGFloat dur;
            if (duration == 0)  {
                dur = .5f;
            }else {
                dur = duration;
            }

            [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:dur options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
                label.frame = CGRectMake(0,-40,320,40);
            }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if (finished) [label removeFromSuperview];
                currentlyDisplayed = NO;
            }];
        }]; 
    }else {
        NSMethodSignature *sig = [[self class] methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(animateDown:view:color:time:)];
        NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
        [invocation setSelector:@selector(animateDown:view:color:time:)];
        [invocation setTarget:self];
        [invocation setArgument:&title atIndex:2];
        [invocation setArgument:&view atIndex:3];
        [invocation setArgument:&color atIndex:4];
        [invocation setArgument:&duration atIndex:5];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 invocation:invocation repeats:NO];
    }
}



- (IBAction)onTap:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:@"announcementTapped" object:nil]];
    NSLog(@"tapped");
}
```

The onTap method is never called....It goes into the if statement..See image:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the method with `customBlue` as the `color` parameter?

Comment: Yes, when I run it in gdb line by line, it does go into the if statement. I even ran this code without the conditional, where a gesture recognizer was added for no matter the color, but the method still isn't called.

Comment: I think the issue is - set the userInteractionEnabled before the IF block. That should make sure tapping on the label calls the action.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Calling it within the IF block or before shouldn't matter since the if block is getting executed either way(when the color is blue)

Comment: What value does `dur` have? When you set it to some high value (say 5 sec.), can you tap the label while it's waiting to move up again?

Comment: Dur has a value of 3s when the user if notified an announcement has been received(blue colored label). I can't click it coming down or going up.

Comment: So just to clarify, you can tap it while it's down (but not currently animating)?

Comment: I can't tap it at all..from the second it's on the screen to the second it's off..I clicked it until it left the view but the method still wasn't called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's failing to recognize the touch because it's being tapped in a `UIView` animation block.

Try adding `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` to the options parameter when animating.

---

### EDIT

The problem is that the actual position of the `UIView`'s layer is at the final destination. What you want to do is check if its `presentationLayer` is at the position which was tapped.

To solve this, you could add the gesture to the main view instead of the actual label, and on tap check if the touch location is within the label's `presentationLayer`:

```
- (IBAction)onTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint point = [tapGestureRecognizer locationInView:tapGestureRecognizer.view];
    BOOL labelTapped = [self.label.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:point] != nil;
    if (labelTapped) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's probably it. How do I enable multiple options? Can I use the Bitwise Operator | ?

Comment: @blackdemon619 yes, e.g.: `options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut`.

Comment: @blackdemon619 I added an alternative answer that definitely works.

Comment: I don't have access to the label in the onTap method, the label is not a property, nor can I make it one since I can't access an instance var from a class method.

Comment: Give it a tag, say 619, and then iterate through the `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s view's subviews and look for the tag.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. I just made the label a global var since only once view can be presented at a time, I shouldn't have any issues. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, this solution did work, but I have yet another problem. When an ad is displayed under the notification I made, the ad absorbs the touch even though the label is on top. How do I make my gestureRecognizer swallow all touches, then if it the touch I need do such and such, and if not, then send the touch the the next subview.

Comment: @blackdemon619 That probably deservers a new question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `Userinteraction` property of `UILabel` is true or false if it is false then set it to true. You can also check inside your storyboard or xib file and accordingly checked it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap:)];  
//...//
- (IBAction)onTap:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
```

Change your `onTap` signature to match your GestureRecognizer class `UITap...`

Comment: @blackdemon619 : UITapGesture and UIPanGesture are not the same and one is not the super class of the other

Comment: @VinceBurn That doesn't matter for the method signature, that's just `onTap:`. Yes, it would be better if the parameter was declared with the type that is actually passed to the method, but it wouldn't have any actual effect here.

Comment: If the signature was wrong, it would still call the method. The method isn't even being called. Still, I changed it to the proper signature.

Comment: @blackdemon619 You are right I've done a small test and it's called event if the inheritance of the parameter doesn't work.